# Why does label always give me empty string when I set Its text using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label

I am setting text of Label (asp.net core component asp:Label) usign jquery but when I get it's text in my .cs file it always give me empty text. What is the problem and how could I solve it.

This is `.aspx` file

```
<button type="button" id="btnMinus" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="" style="width: 50px; height: 60px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
</button>

<input type="number" step="0.50" id="txtPrice" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1.50" max="15.00" min="0.50" style="height: 60px; width: 140px; font-size: 40px" />

<button type="button" id="btnPlus" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="" style="width: 50px; height: 60px; margin-right: 10px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>

<label class="input-group-addon hidden-xs" style="font-size: 40px;"><span>$</span><asp:Label ID="lblPrice" CssClass="lblPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label></label>
```

This is jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnPlus").click(function () {
            if ($("#txtPrice").val().length === 0) {
                $("#txtPrice").val(0.50);
            }
            var price = parseFloat($("#txtPrice").val());
            if (price >= 0.5 && price < 15.00) {
                price += 0.50;
                $("#txtPrice").val(price.toFixed(2));
                $(".lblPrice").text(price.toFixed(2));
            }
        });
        $("#btnMinus").click(function () {
            if ($("#txtPrice").val().length === 0) {
                $("#txtPrice").val(1.50);
            }
            var price = parseFloat($("#txtPrice").val());
            if (price > 0.5 && price <= 15.00) {
                price -= 0.50;
                $("#txtPrice").val(price.toFixed(2));
                $(".lblPrice").text(price.toFixed(2));
            }
        });
        $("#txtPrice").on('input', function (e) {
            var price = parseFloat($("#txtPrice").val());

            if (price <= 15.00 && price >= 0.50) {
                $(".lblPrice").text(Math.round(price).toFixed(2));
            }
            else {
                $(".lblPrice").text("1.00");
            }
        });
    });
```

This code is working fine but `asp:Label` does not give me the value which is set by the jquery.

This is .cs file

```
string value = lblPrice.Text;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Display", "alert('" + value + "')", true);
```

`lblPrice.Text` give empty string

> **Note:** I want to do this in client side not server side. I mean I don't want to handle buttons event in my .cs file because jquery is lighter way to do this.

Comment: How are you expecting the server to know the label has changed with jQuery, which is client side code.

Comment: It means I have to handle event in .cs file instead of jquery?

Comment: You can't set Text property from jQuery... Watch generated html source from  your browser, you will be surprised!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value on txtPrice on server through this line on code

```
string price = Request.Form["txtPrice"].toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

A label's value is not posted back with the page. You can use a hiddenfield and set it's value which can be read server side.

check below code.

```
    <input id="txthiddenvalue" type="hidden" runat="server" />

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#txt").keyup(function(){
            $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").text(this.value);
            $("#txthiddenvalue").val(this.value);
         });
    });

    protected void btnGetValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string LabelValue = txthiddenvalue.Value;
    }
```

Comment: What is Label1.ClientID?

Comment: asp.net generate clientID for each control while rendering to browser.